# SQL Server: What is the default data type of a literal with an exponent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, literals, sql-server-2017

What is the default data type of a literal with an exponent?

For example, what would the default data type be for the literal `5000E0`

Specifically, I need to make sure the default is `FLOAT` (i.e. `FLOAT(53)`)

If the default is `REAL` (i.e. `FLOAT(24)`), then I'm afraid extra implicit casts will be added, slowing down my queries.

Comment: Its a float SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(5000E0, 'BaseType') == float

Comment: SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(5000E0, 'Precision')  == 53 :)

Comment: Another method: `EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 5000E0;';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a 64bit float.

```
select datalength(5000E0)
```

outputs

8

```
select 5000E0 val into #t

select t.name, t.max_length, t.precision
from tempdb.sys.columns c
join sys.types t 
  on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#t')
```

outputs

```
name      max_length precision
--------- ---------- ---------
float     8          53
```